# What is RC or BBS in last column of efibootmgr -v?

Tags: boot, uefi, efibootmgr

xubuntu 20.04 command `efibootmgr -v` has three columns after the BootOrder: line. The third column has either a boot loader entry or "RC" for CD or USB media. My HP laptop has W10 preinstalled with a recovery partition for W10, and of course I have Linux installed on another partition. The third column starts with "HD(foo)" for the W10 boot or Ubuntu boot, and it starts with "BBS HD(foo)" for the W10 recovery partition.

I searched the Internet, perused the 2700+ pages of the UEFI Spec and found that BBS may mean BIOS Boot Specification. But could not find out anything about the "RC" entry in the third column.

Just curious.

Actual output of the command as requested by a comment below

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 2002,2001,0001,0000,0008,2004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,222a7e4f-cb9d-449e-b222-86fbc93595d8,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...5................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,222a7e4f-cb9d-449e-b222-86fbc93595d8,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0005* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot0007* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot0008* Notebook Hard Drive - ST1000LM035-1RK172  BBS(HD,Notebook Hard Drive - ST1000LM035-1RK172,0x500)................-...........A....................................X..|.......A.........................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
```

This is an hp-15bs062st laptop, W10 preinstalled then messed up and reinstalled from hp-Microsoft OS stick.

Boot 0001 is my Ubuntu

Boot 0005, 0007 and 3001 are hard disk partitions used for linux swap and other mounted files

Boot 0000 and 0008 are Windows OS and Recovery

I don't know and don't really care what 2004 is in the boot order

Boot order is fine as is: machine boots into my Ubuntu, but if I have
a bootable USB or CD it boots that not Ubuntu.

If I need W10 I can chose it at boot.

Everything makes sense except RC and why the Windows recovery is marked with BBS - but that's OK. My question was about the RC.

Comment: Could you please copy the output of the command and paste it directly [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1355973/edit)? Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window. This will help us understand your question better.

Comment: This might help:  https://github.com/rhboot/efibootmgr/issues/34#issuecomment-122659778